# Want to get order cancellation rate per week for prior 12 months

Tags: sql, time, databricks, rate

I have a table that has each transaction along with a field that shows how many units were cancelled in the order.  If I filter the table on cancelled_units > 0 i can pull all transactions that are cancelled.  There is also detailed date information for each transaction but I think I only need date.  I need to create a rate calculation of total cancelled orders / total orders to get cancellation rate and then spread that out across every week for the past 12 months.  I was thinking maybe using a CASE statement with some sort of counter in place?  Also, I am using Databricks so maybe there is some built in function or operators that would make this easier.  Appreciate you taking a look at my question.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Answer (score 0):

From the context provided, you have a data frame with the list of transactions. It is also clear that there is a transaction column, the timestamp indicating when the order was placed, and the number of units cancelled in each transaction. So, when you filter your data frame on condition cancelled_units>0, and count the number of fields, you get number of cancelled_orders.

**Using spark in Databricks:**

Now, to find the rate of cancellation (cancelled_orders/total_orders) for every week in the past 12 months. I was able to find a way that allows you to calculate the rate of cancellation in a **PARTICULAR YEAR** (not past 12 months). So, gather all the records in a certain year first.

Since the timestamp indicating when the order was placed is already available in the data frame, we can use this timestamp to find out which week of the year this transaction was made. You can use the following way to achieve this (similar sytax for both pyspark and spark with scala).

`df.withColumn("order_placed_week",date_format(col("transaction_date"), "w")).show()`

Here transaction_date is a timestamp. If it is a date, then use the following method.

`df.withColumn("order_placed_week", date_format(to_date("transaction_date",  "dd/mm/yyyy"), "w")).show()`

`to_date()` function helps you to specify the format of the transaction_date in your data frame.

The libraries that are required to be imported are:

For pyspark:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, date_format, col`

Reference: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/get-month-year-and-quarter-from-date-in-pyspark/

For spark:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Reference: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-how-to-get-a-day-and-week-of-year/

After completing this process, you can use the resulting data frame with order_placed_week column to get cancellation rate.

Get the count of orders for each week number, and then the count of orders with cancelled units using groupBy and filter. Dividing the count_of_cancelled/total_count for each week will give your desired result.